# compiling R package on ubuntu, invalid ELF header

Tags: r, compiler-errors, ubuntu-15.10

I am no longer able to compile an R package from source, and this has never been a problem before today. This is what happens:

```
R CMD build BAMMtools
* checking for file ‘BAMMtools/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘BAMMtools’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* looking to see if a ‘data/datalist’ file should be added
* building ‘BAMMtools_2.1.0.tar.gz’


R CMD INSTALL BAMMtools
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘BAMMtools’ ...
** libs
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BAMMtools/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BAMMtools/libs/BAMMtools.so':
  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BAMMtools/libs/BAMMtools.so: invalid ELF header
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BAMMtools’
* restoring previous ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BAMMtools’
```

This does not seem to be a problem with this R package in particular, as I am able to install the package from within R, as:

```
> install.packages('BAMMtools_2.1.0.tar.gz', repos=NULL)
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘BAMMtools’ ...
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c cohort_matrix.c -o cohort_matrix.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dtrates.c -o dtrates.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c jenksBrks.c -o jenksBrks.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c treetraverse.c -o treetraverse.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o BAMMtools.so cohort_matrix.o dtrates.o jenksBrks.o treetraverse.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BAMMtools/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (BAMMtools)
```

I am running R v3.2.2, under Ubuntu v15.10 wily. I can't think of anything I've done within the last 24 hours that would have this effect, except updating my system with sudo apt-get update/upgrade.

Although this is not too much of a problem for installing the package, I can't run the R CMD check commands either, and this is a problem for development.

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The semi-officially recommended way is indeed to `R CMD INSTALL` the `.tar.gz` file, not the source directory. I've read other people have problems by not installing the `.tar.gz`, and seen R core people say that calling `INSTALL` on a directory is unsupported. This is despite "Both lib and the elements of pkgs may be absolute or relative path names of directories. pkgs may also contain names of package archive files: these are then extracted to a temporary directory." from https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/INSTALL.html

Comment: You are correct: If I R CMD build and then move that package to a different directory, and then R CMD install, it works fine. Apparently, the presence of the source directory is a problem, although it didn't used to be... Thanks!

Comment: Jack is correct, and it more than _semi-official_: it has been _the only recommended way_ for several years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was found in the comments to the question, thanks to [Jack Wasey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3671495/jack-wasey), the problem was simply that I was running `R CMD INSTALL` on the name of the source directory, rather than on the built `.tar.gz` file.